# Is it possible to show only posts with dates older than yesterday

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

as the topic says.

I was hoping this could be done w graphql. The [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/) shows there's a `lt` and `gt` operator, but when I try this locally or the graphiql demo, I get an error, saying the operator is not available...

[index.js](https://github.com/flowen/gatsby-filter-out-old-events/blob/master/src/pages/index.js):

```
export const IndexPageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allEventsJson
      #here I was hoping to filter all past events
      #(filter: { date:{ gte: { today }}})
      #but gte is not accepted and I'm unsure how to set today's date in 
      #the query (iso8601 date through a JS variable was not accepted)
    {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          date(formatString: "DD-MM-YYYY")
          month: date(formatString: "MMM")
          day: date(formatString: "DD")
          year: date(formatString: "YYYY")
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

I have a repository with a [demo here](https://github.com/flowen/gatsby-filter-out-old-events)

Comment: Please show your actual graphql query and the error message.

Comment: “Yes, it’s possible.”. Of course, this was already known - work on meaningful questions (or non-question titles). This is much easier to do if describing the actual error / differering results / supporting evidence etc. in the question body..

Comment: oh my bad, I forgot to add it and lazily clicked post. I added a demo repo and the graphql query

Comment: someone just asked a really similar questions here, maybe [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54473828/how-to-query-date-range-in-gatsby-graphql) there could be helpful

Comment: @DerekNguyen thanks for the answer. Also Jason Lengstorf confirmed to me I should convert to a timestamp. But passing the variables through the context of createPage() means it's only available during build time, right? I need it realtime.

Comment: @flowen i think the variable you passed will be available at anytime for use in `props.pageContext`, but you cannot do graphql on browser side, not without extra setups

Comment: @DerekNguyen yea but momentjs returns an int right in that exampe. So just the int will be passed on. Next time you build, a new value will be passed on. 

Do you know how to do it browserside or perhaps have a reference?

Comment: Check this one out: [gatsby + apollo setup](https://github.com/jlengstorf/gatsby-with-apollo)

Comment: @DerekNguyen sorry not sure what to look at. I'm not going to setup Apollo just for this :)

Comment: but I tried implementing the other answer you gave. 

```The GraphQL query from /Volumes/Data/DOCUMENTS/_htdocs/technoinasia.com/gatsby/src/templates/event-list.js failed.

Errors:
  Cannot read property 'node' of undefined

  GraphQL request (6:3)
  5: ) {
  6:   allEventsJson(sort: {fields: date, order: ASC}, filter: {intDate: {gte: $timestamp}}, limit: $limit, skip: $skip) {
       ^
  7:     edges {
````

It returns this error. When I use a number e.g. 20190302 it works. I checked the type of it and its a number, with the exact same value 

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you need... why don’t you make a new question and add more detail info?

Comment: I meant for the browser side question you asked earlier. For the error you get above, you can edit the current question + add your code since it’s relevant — sorry for the confusion!