# Building a Wordpress blog archive: filtering by date with GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, graphql, gatsby

Currently struggling with building an archive for a Wordpress blog using Gatsby. I'm trying to set it up where you navigate to a url like "localhost:8000/blog/11-19" and it shows all of the blog posts for November 2019. Right now I DO have the site set up where the url is created successfully based off the date, but when I try to loop through the query and actually generate the blog content, nothing appears. My gatsby-node file:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/blog-post.js')
  const blogCategoryFilter = path.resolve('./src/templates/blog-filter-category.js')
  const blogArchiveFilter = path.resolve('./src/templates/blog-filter-archive.js')

  const res = await graphql(`
      query {
        allWordpressPost {
          edges {
            node {
              slug
              date(formatString:"MM-YY")
            }
          }
        }
        allWordpressCategory {
          edges {
            node {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `)

  res.data.allWordpressPost.edges.forEach((edge) => {
    createPage({
      component: blogPostTemplate,
      path: `/blog/${edge.node.slug}`,
      context: {
        slug: edge.node.slug,
      }
    })
  })

  res.data.allWordpressPost.edges.forEach((edge) => {
    createPage({
      component: blogArchiveFilter,
      path: `/blog/${edge.node.date}`,
      context: {
        slug: edge.node.date,
      }
    })
  })

  res.data.allWordpressCategory.edges.forEach((edge) => {
    createPage({
      component: blogCategoryFilter,
      path: `/blog/category/${edge.node.slug}`,
      context: {
        slug: edge.node.slug,
      }
    })
  })

}
```

My template file (in this example, that's blogArchiveFilter--blog-filter-archive.js):

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, Link } from 'gatsby'

import Layout from '../components/layout'
import BlogNav from '../components/blognav'

import blogStyles from '../components/modules/blog.module.css'

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: Date!) {
    allWordpressPost (filter: { date: { eq: $slug }}) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          slug
          content
          date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        }
      }
    }
  }
`






export default ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={blogStyles.blog_container}>
        <div className={blogStyles.blogContent_container}>
          <ol>
            {data.allWordpressPost.edges.map((edge) => {
              return (
                <div className={blogStyles.blogPost_container}>
                  <li className={blogStyles.blog_list}>
                    <h2><Link to={`/blog/${edge.node.slug}`} className={blogStyles.blog_title} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: edge.node.title }}></Link></h2>
                    <p className={blogStyles.blog_date}>{edge.node.date}</p>
                    <p className={blogStyles.blog_content} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: edge.node.content }} />
                  </li>
                </div>
              )
            })}
          </ol>
        </div>
        <BlogNav />
      </div>

    </Layout>
  )
}
```

EDIT:

Is there a way that I can set a variable within a query to change in response to a slug? For example: if the URL was "localhost:8000/blog/2019-11", I could filter gt: "$slug" and filter lt "2019-12". If the URL was "localhost:8000/blog/2019-10" I could filter gt: "$slug" and filter lt "2019-11". This would always generate the posts for the month and year in my URL. Example is below.

It's like if the slug is "2019-(a)", then the lt value would always be "2019-(a+1)". Can that be done?

```
query($slug: Date!){
    allWordpressPost (filter: { date: { gt: $slug, lt: "2019-12" }}) {
      edges {
        node {
          date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54473828/how-to-query-date-range-in-gatsby-graphql